# Send build notes to TestFlight using altool

Tags: jenkins, testflight

I am using altool to push an ipa to Testflight from jenkins. I do not see an option yet to include any build notes. This is a manual process. Is there a way to add details in 'What to Test' using altool? 
I have looked into using curl to send the ipa to Testflight, just that i cannot figure out what the testflight api token and some other information that needs to go with it. So continuing to use altool.

[image]

Comment: I am not ready to start using fastlane yet, itmstrasnporter is another option which i am looking into.